Get the device ID of an input device while using pynput in Linux
How can I get the device ID of an input device (trackball or spinner or mouse) while using pynput(in python) in Linux?
My problem
I want to use the spinner to scroll vertically through long pages very quickly. I am using
mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(
        on_move=on_mouse_move,
        on_scroll=on_mouse_scroll,
        on_click=on_mouse_click)

However the spinner only outputs mouse_move events, not the desired mouse_scroll events and the cursor is moved vertically but the page is not scrolled.
By identifying the input device I could intercept the mouse_move events coming from the spinner while ignoring the mouse_move_events coming from the trackball. These mouse events I could then translate into mouse_scroll events and then the page would be scrolled while using the spinner.
But to do this I must first identify the input device so that I can differentiate between the mouse and the spinner.
How can I identify the input devices within pynput?
I started out by using this pynput statement
mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(
        on_move=on_mouse_move,
        on_scroll=on_mouse_scroll,
        on_click=on_mouse_click)

But the mouse_move events of the trackball and spinner were indistinguishable.

For what you're doing, I wonder if python-evdev would be a better choice? It gives you much more granular control over input devices, but has the limitation that you either need to run it as root or grant your user read (and write, if necessary) access to input devices (/dev/input/*).
